# Gaining real su permission on gnu root debian instead of proot env?

Tags: android, debian-wheezy, gnu, chroot

Im running a samsung galaxy j110H, kitkat 4.4.4, rooted.

Is it possible to attain real super user privillige on gnuroot debian instead of fakerootfs. Is there any way as in when I type in su; there is an actual su prompt asking me to allow it. This is the outcome when I type in su;

```
root@localhost:/# su
setgid: Permission denied
root@localhost:/#
- - snip - -
```

Also apt-get update && apt-get upgrade returns;

```
unpacking python (from .../python_2.7.3-4+deb7u1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't set effective uid: Permission denied
Setting up libexpat1:armel (2.1.0-1+deb7u2) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.3-6+deb7u2) ...
- - snip - -
```

Comment: Just use `chroot` and `mount --bind` commands manually instead of executing `proot`. Latter is only necessarily required for non-rooted devices.

Comment: Damn I need tutorial on that!!